# 301 redirects of full addresses not folders

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, redirect

I have many subdomains within my main example.com like us.example.com, gb.example.com, fr.example.com, pl.example.com etc.

Now I need to do the 301 redirects from the non-existing sites to the new ones. Normally I would have done it the simplest way possible:

```
Redirect 301 /system_example/systems/system_abc.html http://pl.example.com/system_example/systems/all_systems.html
```

But this is not possible in the website structure that I have as all the other subdomains that have that path `/system_example/systems/system_abc.html` will be now redirecting to the `http://pl.example.com/system_example/systems/all_systems.html`

I only want to do the redirects within the pl.example.com subdomain - all the others need to be left untouched. If only this type of redirect worked but it does not:

```
Redirect 301 http://pl.example.com/system_example/systems/system_abc.html http://pl.example.com/system_example/systems/all_systems.html
```

Is it at all possible do achieve that via .htaccess?

Comment: So, this pattern should be applied to all subdomains or just `pl.example.com`?

Comment: Only one subdomain for now. It should work more less like this: Redirect 301 http://pl.example.com/system_example/systems/system_abc.html http://pl.example.com/system_example/systems/all_systems.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have `mod-rewrite` enabled, then:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pl\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(system_example/systems)/system_abc\.html$ /$1/all_systems.html [R=301,L]
```

otherwise, using `mod-alias` only:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST}" == "pl.example.com">
    RedirectPermanent /system_example/systems/system_abc.html /system_example/systems/all_systems.html
</If>
```

I am not sure whether the second one is syntactically correct or not.

Comment: What did I write wrong? It's not working :/


RewriteEngine 
On RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pl.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(system_example/systems)/system_example_pp.html$ /$1/advantages.html [R=301,L]

Comment: @Marcin check if mod-rewrite is active or not. On a linux system, you do `sudo a2enmod rewrite`